# Visual Studio add-in : How to add a command to visual studio's tab context menu?

Tags: visual-studio-addins

I've built a Visual Studio 2008 add-in . I want to add a command to the context menu of the code window's tab . The thing I didn't know is how to get the tab context menu in this way:

```
CommandBars cmdBars = (CommandBars)(_applicationObject.CommandBars);
CommandBar projectFileListMenu = cmdBars["Item"];
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the "Easy MDI Document Window" window using the same method you've written.

```
CommandBar tabCommandBar = cmdBars["Easy MDI Document Window"];
```

Then add your control to this command bar.